# How can I query for overlapping date ranges?

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, overlapping

I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2 and trying to create a query that will show whether dates overlap.

I'm trying to calculate the number of days someone is covered under a certain criteria.  Here is an example of the table...

```
CREATE TABLE    mytable
(   

CARDNBR varchar(10) 
GPI char(14)    ,
GPI_DESCRIPTION_10  varchar(50) ,
RX_DATE datetime    ,
DAYS_SUPPLY int ,
END_DT  datetime    ,
METRIC_QUANTITY float   

)       
INSERT INTO mytable VALUES ('1234567890','27200040000315','Glyburide','01/30/2013','30','03/01/2013','60')      
INSERT INTO mytable VALUES ('1234567890','27200040000315','Glyburide','03/04/2013','30','04/03/2013','60')      
INSERT INTO mytable VALUES ('1234567890','27250050007520','Metformin','01/03/2013','30','02/02/2013','120')     
INSERT INTO mytable VALUES ('1234567890','27250050007520','Metformin','02/27/2013','30','03/29/2013','120')
```

I want to be able to count the number of days that a person was covered from the first RX_DATE to the last END_DT, which in this example is 90 days (4/3/13 - 1/3/13).

That part is done, but this is where I'm getting into trouble.

Between row 1 and row 2, there was a 3 day period where there were no drugs being taken.  Between rows 3 and 4 there was a 25 day period.  However, during that 25 day period, row 1 covered that gap.  So the end number I need to show is 3 for the gap between rows 1 and 2.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Please show what queries you have tried that didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be a better approach, but you could create a lookup of days, join to it and select the distinct days that join, that will get you the total count of days covered for all lines:

```
CREATE TABLE #lkp_Calendar (Dt DATE)
GO
SET NOCOUNT ON
DECLARE @intFlag INT
SET @intFlag = 1
WHILE (@intFlag <=500)
BEGIN
--Loop through this:
INSERT INTO #lkp_Calendar 
SELECT DATEADD(day,@intFlag,'20120101')
SET @intFlag = @intFlag + 1
END
GO
```

--Days Covered

```
SELECT CARDNBR, COUNT(DISTINCT b.Dt)CT
FROM  #mytable a
JOIN #lkp_Calendar b
    ON b.Dt BETWEEN a.RX_DATE AND a.END_DT
GROUP BY CARDNBR
```

--Total Days

```
SELECT CARDNBR, DATEDIFF(DAY,MIN(RX_DATE),MAX(END_DT))+1 'Total_Days'
        FROM #mytable
        GROUP BY CARDNBR
```

--Combined

```
SELECT covered.CARDNBR, covered.CT 'Days Covered', total.Total_Days 'Total Days', total.Total_Days - covered.CT 'Days Gap'
FROM  (SELECT CARDNBR, COUNT(DISTINCT b.Dt)CT
        FROM  #mytable a
        JOIN #lkp_Calendar b
            ON b.Dt BETWEEN a.RX_DATE AND a.END_DT
        GROUP BY CARDNBR
      )covered
JOIN (SELECT CARDNBR, DATEDIFF(DAY,MIN(RX_DATE),MAX(END_DT))+1 'Total_Days'
        FROM #mytable
        GROUP BY CARDNBR
     )total
ON covered.CARDNBR = total.CARDNBR
```

You said 90 days, but I believe  you should have 91.  Date diff from Mon-Wed is only 2, but that's 3 days covered. But you can decide if coverage begins on the rx date or the day after.

Comment: That just gives me a return value of 91, which is just counting the days.  I can count the days, but I need to count where there was no coverage at all by any drugs.

Comment: In your example there is no gap, unless you are looking per drug.  The gap between 1 and 2 is covered by 4.