# Calculate Price For Overlapping Date Range

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a simple table named HotelRate

```
HID  |  START_DATE  |   END_DATE    |   PRICE_PER_DAY
--------------------------------------
1        01/1/2015       10/1/2015       100
1        11/1/2015       20/1/2015       75
1        21/1/2015       30/1/2015       110
```

what is the most simple way to calculate price for Hotel Room if user queries for Total Price between `5/1/2015` to `25/1/2015`.

I have checked :

- [How can I query for overlapping date ranges?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16944258/how-can-i-query-for-overlapping-date-ranges)
- [Overlapping date range MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3667668/overlapping-date-range-mysql)

but none of it is making much sense to me.

I have tried a couple queries but those seems like hitting arrow in the blind. Can someone suggest me a simple and elegant way to do it ?

---

@JamesZ

On running the first query i get

```
start_date end_date   duration    price_per_day
---------- ---------- ----------- -------------
2015-01-01 2015-01-10 5           100
2015-01-11 2015-01-20 9           75
2015-01-21 2015-01-30 4           110
```

For first range `5` is OK, second range it should be `10`, third be `5`

How days are calculated : Total no of nights between `start` & `end` date, which is same as days difference

```
05-Jan-15   06-Jan-15   1 Night
06-Jan-15   07-Jan-15   1 Night
07-Jan-15   08-Jan-15   1 Night
08-Jan-15   09-Jan-15   1 Night
09-Jan-15   10-Jan-15   1 Night
10-Jan-15   11-Jan-15   1 Night
11-Jan-15   12-Jan-15   1 Night
12-Jan-15   13-Jan-15   1 Night
13-Jan-15   14-Jan-15   1 Night
14-Jan-15   15-Jan-15   1 Night
15-Jan-15   16-Jan-15   1 Night
16-Jan-15   17-Jan-15   1 Night
17-Jan-15   18-Jan-15   1 Night
18-Jan-15   19-Jan-15   1 Night
19-Jan-15   20-Jan-15   1 Night
20-Jan-15   21-Jan-15   1 Night
21-Jan-15   22-Jan-15   1 Night
22-Jan-15   23-Jan-15   1 Night
23-Jan-15   24-Jan-15   1 Night
24-Jan-15   25-Jan-15   1 Night
               Count : 20 Night
```

Comment: So is this MySQL or MS SQL Server?

Comment: @Mureinik Sql Server

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
declare @startdate date, @enddate date

set @startdate = '20150105'
set @enddate = '20150125'

select
  start_date,
  end_date,
  datediff(
    day, 
    case when @startdate > start_date then @startdate else start_date end, 
    case when @enddate < end_date then @enddate else end_date end) as duration,
  price_per_day
from
  reservation
where
  end_date >= @startdate and
  start_date <= @enddate
```

This just handles the overlapping ranges with case so that if the reservation start is the correct one to use, it takes it, otherwise the search criteria, and same thing for end date. The days and price are here separate, but you can just multiply them to get the result.

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4027b3/1

Edit, this way to get total sum:

```
declare @startdate date, @enddate date

set @startdate = '20150105'
set @enddate = '20150125'

select
  sum(datediff(
    day, 
    case when @startdate > start_date then @startdate else start_date end, 
    case when @enddate < end_date then @enddate else end_date end)  
  * price_per_day)
from
  reservation
where
  end_date >= @startdate and
  start_date <= @enddate
```

Comment: I left it out intentionally, since this gives better idea what the SQL does. To get total sum on one row, just have sum(datediff(...) * price_per_day) in the sql.

Comment: Isn't it off by 1? The number of days is calculated non-inclusive, so I think you need to add 1 to the duration to make it inclusive.

Comment: @JamesZ this seems great, the start & end date seems exclusive, in my case it needed to be inclusive!

Comment: @PaRiMaLRaJ Sorry, my bad. Fixed the ranges

Comment: @JamesZ shouldn't the duration for the last section be 5 ?

Comment: @PaRiMaLRaJ That depends on the definition of calculation. I would assume it's normal hotel nights, so 21 - 22, 22 - 23, 23 - 24 and 24 - 25 = 4 nights, but of course if your search range should also include the night 25 - 26th, then just add one day to the end.

Comment: @PaRiMaLRaJ Your data is somehow strange, since the example doesn't really include the night 10 - 11 (or 20 - 21), but you're calculating it too. If it is supposed to be included, I would assume adding +1 after the datediff could fix that, but check all the cases related to search criteria being around the ending of the reservation so that the dates included are ok.

Comment: @JamesZ - yes i ended up adding` +1` to difference and subtract 1 day from `@endDate`.

Thank you very much for your time. Will add bounty as it is eligible!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78343/discussion-between-parimal-raj-and-jamesz).

Comment: @JamesZ just a small question, is this way to calculate fast or there are other way for gaining more performance?

Comment: Performance depends on a lot of things. Date ranges with 2 fields aren't the best for performance because you can't limit the range with one key. If you usually fetch data that is near to current day or in the future (and most of the data is in past) that's something you can think of in indexing.

Answer (score 3):

You will need a calendar table, but every database should have one.
The actual implementation is always user and DBMS specific (e.g. [MS SQL Server](http://web.archive.org/web/20070611150639/http://sqlserver2000.databases.aspfaq.com/why-should-i-consider-using-an-auxiliary-calendar-table.html)), so searching for "calendar table" + yourDBMS will probably reveal some source code for your system.

```
select HID, sum(PRICE_PER_DAY)
from calendar_table as c
join HotelRate
  on calendar_date between START_DATE and END_DATE
group by HID
```

Answer (score 1):

This is easy to handle if you have an existing table of dates to work with. Don't have one already? Below you'll find two functions to help you get started. This is how you use them:

```
-- Arguments can be passed in any order
SELECT * FROM dbo.RangeDate('2015-12-31', '2015-01-01');
SELECT * FROM dbo.RangeSmallInt(10, 0);

SELECT A.HID, SUM(A.PRICE_PER_DAY)
FROM dbo.RangeDate('2000-01-01', '2020-12-31') Calendar
JOIN HotelRate A
    ON Calendar.D BETWEEN A.START_DATE and A.END_DATE
GROUP BY A.HID;
```

You can use the RangeDate function as a calendar or you can use it to build your own calendar function/table.

```
-- Generate a range of up to 65,536 contiguous DATES
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.RangeDate (   
    @date1 DATE = NULL
  , @date2 DATE = NULL
)   
RETURNS TABLE   
AS   
RETURN (
    SELECT D = DATEADD(DAY, A.N, CASE WHEN @date1 <= @date2 THEN @date1 ELSE @date2 END)
    FROM dbo.RangeSmallInt(
        CASE WHEN @date1 IS NOT NULL AND @date2 IS NOT NULL THEN 0 END
      , ABS(DATEDIFF(DAY, @date1, @date2))
    ) A
);

-- Generate a range of up to 65,536 contiguous BIGINTS
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.RangeSmallInt (
    @n1 BIGINT = NULL
  , @n2 BIGINT = NULL
)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN (
    WITH Numbers AS (
        SELECT N FROM(VALUES
            (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1) -- 16
          , (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1) -- 32
          , (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1) -- 48
          , (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1) -- 64
          , (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1) -- 80
          , (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1) -- 96
          , (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1) -- 112
          , (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1) -- 128
          , (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1) -- 144
          , (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1) -- 160
          , (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1) -- 176
          , (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1) -- 192
          , (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1) -- 208
          , (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1) -- 224
          , (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1) -- 240
          , (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1) -- 256
        ) V (N)
    )    
    SELECT TOP (
               CASE
                   WHEN @n1 IS NOT NULL AND @n2 IS NOT NULL THEN ABS(@n2 - @n1) + 1
                   ELSE 0
               END
           )
           N = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) - 1 + CASE WHEN @n1 <= @n2 THEN @n1 ELSE @n2 END
    FROM Numbers A, Numbers B
    WHERE ABS(@n2 - @n1) + 1 < 65537
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this which will work out the price per period and then sum it up for the total cost. It uses a case statement to work out how many days are in each period so in your example this is 5,9 and 4:

```
Declare @startdate date = '2015-01-05',
        @todate date = '2015-01-25'

Select sum(price_per_period) as TotalPrice -- The cost for all periods is summed to give a total
from
-- First it works out the number of days in the period with a case statement and then
-- multiplies this by the daily rate to get the total for that period
(Select price_per_day * case when Start_date <= @startdate then DATEDIFF(day, @startdate,end_date) else  
    case when Start_date > @startdate and end_date < @todate then DATEDIFF(day, start_date,end_date) else 
        case when Start_date > @startdate and end_date >= @todate then  DATEDIFF(day, start_date, @todate) end
        end
    end price_per_period

 from pricetable
 where (Start_date between @Startdate and @todate) or 
      (end_date between @Startdate and @todate)
) a
```

This eliminates the need for a seperate calendar table

SQL Fiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/25e63/4/0

Answer (score 1):

This should be fast enough as you first generate calendar and then using only join. Also for total price per hotel could be achieved with grouping sets:

Data definition:

```
create table HotelRate(HID int, START_DATE date, END_DATE date, PRICE_PER_DAY int);

insert into HotelRate values
(1, '20150101', '20150110', 100),
(1, '20150111', '20150120', 75),
(1, '20150121', '20150130', 110),
(2, '20150101', '20150110', 10),
(2, '20150111', '20150120', 5),
(2, '20150121', '20150130', 50)
```

Query:

```
declare @sd date = '20150105' , @ed date = '20150125'

;with c as(select @sd d union all select dateadd(dd, 1, d) from c where d < @ed)
select h.HID, h.START_DATE, h.END_DATE, sum(PRICE_PER_DAY) PRICE
from c join HotelRate h on c.d >= h.START_DATE and c.d < h.END_DATE
group by grouping sets((h.HID, h.START_DATE, h.END_DATE),(h.HID))
```

Output:

```
HID START_DATE  END_DATE    PRICE
1   2015-01-01  2015-01-10  500
1   2015-01-11  2015-01-20  675
1   2015-01-21  2015-01-30  550
1   (null)      (null)      1725
2   2015-01-01  2015-01-10  50
2   2015-01-11  2015-01-20  45
2   2015-01-21  2015-01-30  250
2   (null)      (null)      345
```

This can be further optimized with tally tables. And even more, if you create calendar table in your database, it will be instant.

Here is the fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/25e7bc/1

Suppose you have created some calendar table `Calendar(d date)` which contains dates starting from for instance `1900-01-01` ending `2100-01-01`. Add indexes on `Calendar` and `HotelRange` tables on date columns. Then above query can be rewritten as:

```
select h.HID, h.START_DATE, h.END_DATE, sum(PRICE_PER_DAY) PRICE
from Calendar c join HotelRate h on c.d >= h.START_DATE and c.d < h.END_DATE
where c.d between @sd and @ed
group by grouping sets((h.HID, h.START_DATE, h.END_DATE),(h.HID))
```